# Why the Fortran language standard does not standardize built-in collections such as list, map, and so forth?

Tags: standards, fortran

**Summarization:**
Because Fortran is so good at numberical/scientific analyses, and not intended to be a general-purpose language.

================================================

The Java languange has a rich set of built-in collections. The most famous third-party collections are also from reliable Apache foundations and Google corporation (just to name a few).

The Delphi language (dialect) also has a handful set of built-in collections. There are also notational third-party collections such as DIContainers, DeHL, and so forth.

I am wondering why the Fortran language standard does not standarize built-in collections such as list, map, and so forth? I mean, although the standard Fortran 77 does not support pointer, some of its extensions and the successor such as Fortran 90 already have the pointer type?

Comment: @Michael: I added Java and Delphi tag because then the experts from those fields can also comment about this issue. Is that not allowed?

Comment: @Michael: I will add the Delphi tag again, but if it is not allowed, just tell me.

Comment: @Xichen: I don't see how someone working in Java or Delphi would have much input into (or interest in) what goes into the Fortran standard.

Comment: @Michael: But their comments are helpful (if even sparse)?

Comment: @Xichen nothing to do with Delphi.

Comment: @Xichen: You could make that same argument for adding just about any language tag to this question, since many languages or frameworks come with collection types. That doesn't make those tags more relevant to the question at hand. If I ask, "in C#.NET the syntax for doing *whichever* is *something*, how do I do the same thing in Perl?", that doesn't make it a C# question, it only means that I am more familiar with the C#.NET syntax and usage than I am familiar with the Perl syntax.

Comment: @Michael: Oh, fair enough. Thanks for your comments!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fortran's focus has always been high performance numerical computing. Remember that [Fortran first appeared in 1957](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fortran) and so carries a lot of historical baggage.

There has been lots of development to the Fortran language over the years, but those that have been developing it have concentrated on functionality that enables high performance numerical computing.

Fundamentally Fortran is not intended to be a general purpose programming language with the breadth of applications of, say, C++.

Answer (score 4):

The requested data structures have been implemented in the FLIBS project http://flibs.sourceforge.net/ . Perhaps the standards committee thought that with the pointer and allocatable array features of Fortran 90, programmers who wanted other data structures would be able to code them.

Comment: Thanks for your time! I disagree with your opinion. I am aware of flibs. Great as it is, I would think programmers will definitely hold much more faith in standardized collections.

Answer (score 4):

Fortran standard is very carefully put document, for several reasons. One of the main ones is that what goes in the standard will be very difficult to throw out, and the implementation issues also matter. Also there are platform issues.

But most probable reason is, since the Standard is "developed" by compiler developers, and they are in direct connection with the user's demands, is that there wasn't that much of a demand for it from the actual users.

There are currently much more important issues waiting to be implemented than those imho; but that would take a much longer discussion.